# timer accuracy in JavaScript vs ReactJS vs. online timer

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, timer, react-hooks

I have implemented a countdown timer in both vanilla JavaScript and in ReactJS, and when compared the timer between the two programs, and with an online [clock](https://www.online-stopwatch.com/countdown-timer/) or the countdown timer in my mobile, I have notice that the timer in ReactJS tends to drift over time, while the timer in vanilla JavaScript remains at constant speed compared to the online clock.

Specifically, I first ran the timer in my ReactJS app, then the timer in my JS app, and then the timer in the online clock, and initially the timer of my React app was ahead by 1s from the timer in JS, which in turn was ahead by 1s from the online clock. But after about 20 minutes, the timer of my React app was 1s behind the timer of my JS app, while the timer of my JS app remained 1s ahead of the online clock. In other words, the timer in my React app drifted 2s in delay after 20 minutes.

Below are my codes

**React**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [sessionTime, setSessionTime] = useState(82.5);
  const [breakTime, setBreakTime] = useState(7.5);
  const [clockTime, setClockTime] = useState(82.5 * 60);
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState('session');
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = convertTime(clockTime);
    if (isPlaying) {
      let startTime = new Date();
      const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        if (clockTime === 0) {
          setCurrent(current === 'session' ? 'break' : 'session');
          setClockTime(
            current === 'session' ? breakTime * 60 : sessionTime * 60
          );
        } else {
          setClockTime(
            clockTime - (new Date().getTime() - startTime.getTime()) / 1000
          );
          // }
        }
      }, 200);
      return () => {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
      };
    }
  }, [isPlaying, clockTime]);

  const handlePlayClick = () => {
    setIsPlaying(true);
  };

  const handlePauseClick = () => [setIsPlaying(false)];

  const convertTime = (count) => {
    let hours = Math.floor(count / 3600);
    let minutes = Math.floor(count / 60) - hours * 60;
    let seconds = parseFloat(count % 60).toFixed(0);
    if (hours < 10) hours = `0${hours}`;
    if (minutes < 10) minutes = `0${minutes}`;
    if (seconds < 10) seconds = `0${seconds}`;
    return `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
  };
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <span>{convertTime(clockTime)}</span>
      <span>{current}</span>
      {isPlaying ? (
        <button onClick={handlePauseClick}>Pause</button>
      ) : (
        <button onClick={handlePlayClick}>Play</button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**vanilla JS**

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Count down timer</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span id="time-passed"></span>
    <button id="play">Play</button>
    <button id="pause">Pause</button>
  </body>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

app.js

```
const playBtn = document.querySelector('#play');
const pauseBtn = document.querySelector('#pause');

let counter = 82.5 * 60;
let timePassedElem = document.getElementById('time-passed');

const convertTime = (count) => {
  let hours = Math.floor(count / 3600);
  let minutes = Math.floor(count / 60) - hours * 60;
  let seconds = parseFloat(count % 60).toFixed(0);
  if (hours < 10) hours = `0${hours}`;
  if (minutes < 10) minutes = `0${minutes}`;
  if (seconds < 10) seconds = `0${seconds}`;
  return `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
};
let intervalId;
playBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let startTime = new Date();
  intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    document.title = convertTime(
      counter + Math.floor((startTime.getTime() - new Date().getTime()) / 1000)
    );
    timePassedElem.innerText = convertTime(
      counter + Math.floor((startTime.getTime() - new Date().getTime()) / 1000)
    );
  }, 200);
});

pauseBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('clicked');
  clearInterval(intervalId);
});
```

My question is why the timer in my ReactJS drifts over time while this doesn't happen in vanilla JS?

Comment: I think your effect hook is creating a new `startTime` on every render.

Comment: OK, that seemed to have fixed the issue, but when I opened 20 YouTube videos (I am trying to emulate a heavy duty work I will be doing on other tabs while the timer is running) both timers in React and in JS stopped (I see the time on the tab title), and when I opened the tabs, the pages reloaded, and the timers set to their initial state. How can I prevent that from happening?

Comment: Actually it didn't solve the problem. Now it takes longer for the React timer to drift, but it drifts, nonetheless!!